# No output in quicksort

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I'm trying to implement a quicksort function in JavaScript:

```
function partition(l, low, high) {
  l[0] = l[low];
  var pivotkey = l[low];
  while (low < high) {
    while (low < high && pivotkey <= l[high]) {
      --high;
    }
    l[low] = l[high];
    while (low < high && l[low] <= pivotkey) {
      ++low;
    }
    l[high] = l[low];
  }
  l[low] = l[0];
  return low;
}

function qsort(l, low, high) {
  var pivotloc;
  if (low < high) {
    pivotloc = partition(l, low, high);
    qsort(l, low, pivotloc - 1);
    qsort(l, pivotloc + 1, high);
  }
  return;
}

function quickSort(l) {
  qsort(l, 1, l.length - 1);
  return l;
}

console.log(quickSort([0, 1, 4, 3]));
```

But this program output nothing in the terminal (with `node qsort.js`). Perhaps I'm missing something.  Can anyone point me in the right direction? How to debug this kind of problems?

Comment: is the l[0] a temporary case or is it a part of the array to be sorted ????

Comment: @Meninx It isn't a part of the array to be sorted. Please see my comments in the C-like version (URI is commented under your answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you stated the first element of the array will be used as a temporary variable which will be only useful for the execution of the algorithm and which wasn't clear at first !

Your algorithm works fine but you have problem in printing the result !

To get what you want you need to get rid of the first element by adding the `shift()` function in the `quickSort()` block so it becomes :

```
function quickSort(l) {
  qsort(l, 1, l.length - 1);
  l.shift(); // add this function
  return l;
}
```

There is another solution if you want by using the `splice()` function which removes the first element also and which has this form :

```
array.splice(indexToRemove, numberToRemove);
```

so to get the required resutl add the instruction above to your `quickSort()` function like this:

```
function quickSort(l) {
  qsort(l, 1, l.length - 1);
   l.splice(0, 1); //add this line
  return l;
}
```

These are the two solutions I guess for your problem. Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are several issues with your algorithm. But the one I can notice immediately is related to you using `l.low` and `l.high` in your `partition` function. I'm assuming that `l` is an array in which case, both of these are intended to access the indices at `low` and `high`. If that's the case, then these should be `l[low]` and `l[high]`.

Since it seems like you're trying to do an in-place version of quick sort, take a look at what's available here: [In Place Quick Sort](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/11/27/computer-science-in-javascript-quicksort/)

Comment: Oops, `l.low` and `l.high` were typos. I have corrected them in the question/code, but there's still no output.

Comment: Thanks for the link BTW. I have read Nicholas' excellent article before, but I'd like to implement one on my own.